# "Perspective Transform" for UV maps?

Tags: uv

I have a human trunk UV map as below. Is it possible to perform a sort of perspective transform like in Photoshop, where I can widen the top two handles of an imaginary rectangle bounding box and make the upper (neck) end of the UV map be of comparable width to the bottom (butt) half? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use proportional editing with a linear falloff. See the gif below:

[image]

Hope this helps! Peace and God bless!

Comment: Dang, pretty clever use of proportional editing :)

Comment: Sweet technique! Thanks!